# Why do transformers use separate K and V networks

Tags: neural-networks, transformers

In transformers, two separate networks $\phi_k, \phi_q$ compute the keys and queries. The attention weight is then the dot product of the keys and queries. (i.e. $score = \phi_k(z_1) \cdot \phi_q(z_2)$)

This seems overly complex. Why don't we use a single neural network $\phi$ to compute the attention scores directly (i.e. $scores = \phi( concatenate(z_1, z_2) )$).

The latter approach seems simpler and likely uses less parameters than the former. Is there something I'm missing for why the first approach is preferred?

Comment: You don’t have a dot product in your proposal. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes, that is correct. There is no dot-product needed since the input contains both tokens.